# CakePHP: Best practice for validating inputs not present in Model

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a form with inputs that do not really belong inside any model. Things like "confirm password" and "I accept these conditions" etc.

What is the best practice for situations such as this?

I thought about the following possibilities:

1. Create a temporary model inside the controller action with validation rules.
2. Create a separate model for these inputs.
3. Some other feature in cake 2.x specifically for this situation?

I've read many answer posts about this but either the answer is for v1.x of cake and might be outdated, or people propose to put all that stuff inside the model with the closest relationship to the current controller. So what is the best practice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use behaviors for that.

Password add/edit:
https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/blob/master/src/Model/Behavior/PasswordableBehavior.php
( see https://www.dereuromark.de/2011/08/25/working-with-passwords-in-cakephp/ )

Accept Conditions:
https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/blob/master/src/Model/Behavior/ConfirmableBehavior.php
( see https://www.dereuromark.de/2011/07/05/introducing-two-cakephp-behaviors/ )

This allows me a DRY approach without having to repeat it all over again in the different models where I use them. I just add them dynamically (`$this->Behaviors->load()`) or via `$actsAs` and can use the extended functionality (similar to Traits in PHP5.4).

You could put your password validate stuff into the APP user model for a single app. But as soon as you are maintaining multiple apps the code would have to be duplicate at some point. That's why I prefer the behaviorable approach.
But it is neither impossible nor impractible for some situations to just drop the validation in the respective models.
Just don't create temporary models or something. That usually is the wrong way to go.